# How to show a List in a ComboBox in a ListView in MVVM Light?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, observablecollection, itemssource

I have a object that has a few properties like name, date and then a property list tags. This property is a list of tags. I want to show a ListView with the name and then a ComboBox with all the names in that tag list.

Like this:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="3"
                  Margin="10,0,10,0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Foreground="Black" />
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

And this is my ObservableCollection on the ViewModel:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MyObject> _ObjectList = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
 public ObservableCollection<MyObject> ObjectList
 {
     get
     {
          return _ObjectList;
     }
     set
     {
          _ObjectList = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged("ObjectList");
     }
 }
```

How do I get those names into a ComboBox within a ListView? In that ComboBox I see this App1.Model.Object 5 times! There are 5 items in but I want to show the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal beause your `Tag` is an object, you have to define which property `you want to show

Here is an example :

```
 public class Tag
 {
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}

    public string Description {get; set;}

 }
```

Now in your XAML, you will bind this property by adding :

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}", DisplayMemberPath=Description, Mode=Default/>
```

Comment: Ah damn yes indeed now I see the names, but how come only my first comboxbox is filled and all the rest is empty? I'm sure there are items :D

Comment: why do you have _TagList = value; instead of _ObjectList=value; in your code ? can you check please ?

Comment: Changed it to _ObjectList = value

Comment: are you having for each object in your ObjectList a filled tagList with full information ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define, what property should be used for naming the Elements in the Combobox. You can do this with the Property `DisplayMemberPath`. In this example `TagName` is the PropertyName which holds the name of the item.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" DisplayMemberPath="TagName" />
```